# Get attribute ID of a Div element that's being dragged with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, attributes, drag

Recently I've been trying to get the **id**="whatever-id" attribute of a Div that is being dragged, but I haven't succeeded so far. Below you'll find my code (only the dragging part) where I try to get this ID attribute with ui and event objects, but I can't see where is the problem on it.

```
$(function() 
{
    $( ".action-zone" ).draggable(
    { 
        scroll: true,
        helper:"clone",
        snap: ".actionDropAreaMovebleAction",
        snapMode: "inner",
        snapTolerance: 50,
        opacity: 0.7,
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        forceHelperSize: true,
        start: function( event, ui ) 
        {
            alert(ui.draggable.attr("id"));

            //INSERT THE DROP ZONE DIV IN ALL ELEMENTS EXCEPT ON THOSE WHOSE CLASS IS DRAGGINGACTION
            $( ".action-zone:not(.draggingAction)" ).after( "<div class='actionDropAreaMovebleAction'>\n\
                                            <div class='plus'>\n\
                                                <i class='fa fa-hand-o-down'></i>\n\
                                            </div>\n\
                                        </div>" );

            $(".actionDropAreaMovebleAction").addClass("highlighted");
            makeActionsDroppable();
        },
        stop:function( event, ui ) 
        {
            $(".actionDropAreaMovebleAction").removeClass("highlighted");
            $("div").remove(".actionDropAreaMovebleAction");
            $(this).removeClass("draggingAction");
            //alert("hallo");
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I try to "**alert**()" the **attribute ID** of the DIV element with class "**action-zone**" just for test purpose, but when the alert comes I get an "**undefined**" element back.

Does anyone have any idea why this' been happening ?

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `ui.draggable` to get the draggable object when dropping it to somewhere else, like you can catch the object in `droppable`:

```
$(".drop-zone").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.draggable); // will give you the draggable object
  }
});
```

However, in your `draggable`'s `start` event, you might get the id of you object like this:

```
$(".action-zone").draggable({
  start: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.draggable); // will give you undefined
    console.log(event.target.id); // will give you the id
    console.log(event.target.attr('id')); // error!
    console.log($(event.target).attr('id')); // will give you the id
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello lozy219. I've tried to output "event.target.id" inside the draggable function before and it hadn't worked neither. I've just applied your suggestions inside the droppable function and it didn't work neigther. I'm still getting undefined. look: http://www.imageno.com/78qs52xowtnzpic.html

Comment: Without more detail I can't tell what's wrong with the drag and drop event. Here is a very simple demo showing that how the id is fetched through `event.target`. I used the html example from jquery site. https://jsbin.com/sisigurexu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You're right. It really works. I mean, I've created a separated file and used this code you created and it did worked, but somehow inside my main code it's not working... I gotta take a look at the my whole code, cuz' something doesn't match.. thank you for your help Lozy